# Display HTML text to Label,TextView

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel

I have to display HTML text in Label & UITextView in my app.

In iOS 7 it works fine as following:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:
    [HTMLstr dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:
        @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} 
        documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

But it will crash my app if I used same method in iOS 6.

**Thanks**

Comment: Did you check if NSHTMLTextDocumentType is available on iOS 6 or not? Normally I do manually string scanning to remove HTML tags from HTML string and then assign it to UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

`NSHTMLTextDocumentType` is available only in iOS 7.0 and later.

Reference: [NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688-CH1-SW35)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText, what it does is to display all kinds of html content in all kinds of native iOS controls, and it is actively being maintained.

I just added it in my project so I am pretty sure it is what you need. You can easily start using it by looking at the demo project.

BTW, it supports iOS6 (tested in my project) and prior (not tested).